# How to collect data from Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

How can I create a reporting application that collects data from Google Analytics, processes it and returns it for my own custom reporting solution?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the requirements. You plan to run your own analytics afterwards? Or Archives will be used to predict future trends. As such Google Analytics can do it  but if you want to do more with the Analytics data, I guess it is good to archive data on daily basis.
You can start here http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataDeveloperGuide.html

Comment: I agree with JSteve: it depends. the base Google Analytics tool provided will likely give whomever would need it 95% of the answers needed (the caveat here depends upon how you have set up you client code and what features you are tracking in custom variables and the like).

But if you absolutely have to build you own, then look at the APIs provided by Google. I have demoed these for a client in the past, and the samples will save you a ton of time.
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataLibraries.html

Answer (score 0):

You didn't precise how you would like to collect the data, but I suppose you'll want to run some server script to fetch and process data.

I used the following library to get analytics data from PHP and was quite pleased with it:

http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/

For Rubyists, I would recommend GARB, which has decent features and traction:

github.com/vigetlabs/garb

Note: add http:// to the link for garb, since I could not post more than one link.